# Running javascript in an iframe to show an alert

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I'm hosting a PDF in an iFrame on an ASP.Net page and want to set an alert to go off after a time interval of activity.  Because I can't capture any events within the iFrame, I can't check for mouse movement, scrolling, clicks or anything that I can use to detect whether the user is active or not.  (After 20 minutes of inactivity, I want to display an alert)

What I need is a way to run the javascript in the iFrame or write some jquery that can detect events within the iFrame.  Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just load jQuery in the html file that the iframe points too? You should be able to use jQuery within the iFrame html normally?